# Finding max value per group in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

From the following table (called Student):

```
name    course    mark    
A       a         100
A       c         78
A       d         83
B       a         79
B       b         91
C       c         78
C       d         65
D       a         75
```

I'm trying to find the names where the highest mark was in course 'a'.So in this case, A and D should be in the answer, but my query seems to only report the max mark of all students:

```
SELECT name
FROM Student
WHERE mark >= all
    (SELECT mark FROM Student WHERE course='a');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close! Just move things around and you're good. No need for anything complicated.

```
SELECT name
FROM Student s
WHERE course = 'a' AND mark >= all
     (SELECT mark FROM Student WHERE name = s.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for `row_number()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over by (partition by name order by mark desc) as seqnum
      from student s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```